# Copy constructor for class with abstract member in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, directx, abstract-class, copy-constructor

I want to **add a copy constructor** to my **class that has member of abstract type**.

I that case, the **abstract member** is `DirecX::ID3D11Buffer * buffer`, which I initialize in my class after constructor, in separete method `init()`:

```
bool Model::init(){ //create the constant buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBufferStructure);
    ...
    return device->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &constantBuffer) == S_OK;
}
```

I call method `init()` before calling method `render()`, but **not** just after constructor - I choose best moment for it, so it won't slow down the program.

I tried to write the copy constructor like this:

```
class Model: virtual public SomeClassesNotImportantHere...{
    protected: 
        bool visible;
        ID3D11Buffer * constantBuffer; //per object constant buffer

    public:
        Model(){
            visible = true;
        }

        Model& operator=(const Model &other){
            visible = other.visible;
            constantBuffer = new ID3D11Buffer(*constantBuffer);
            return *this;
        }

        Model& operator=(const Model &other) : visible(other.visible){
            constantBuffer = new ID3D11Buffer(*constantBuffer);
            return *this;
        }

        bool init(){...}
        ...
};
```

But in the line:

```
constantBuffer = new ID3D11Buffer(*constantBuffer);
```

I get error:

```
error C2259: 'ID3D11Buffer' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

My question is:

### **How to make a deep copy of that abstract member?**

I **cannot and I should not modify the `Direct::ID3D11Buffer`** class.

And I want to make a deep copy of object (make the copy of the object that is pointed, not the pointer's value).

In my case, it's about Direct class, but as well it can be **an abstract class** from any other third-party library.

Comment: Do you **really** need to copy a `Model`? Or are you providing these member functions "just in case"? If `Model` manages a resource such as a `ID3D11Buffer`, the best shot would be to make the class *movable*.

Comment: I do, for make another instance of the object. E.g. I don't want to load house twice from file, I want to copy it from first Model - get same vertex/index/constant buffers and ability to modify constant buffer of the copy (to change only part of it, vertex/index buffers are static but's a bit out of topic here). And I also have similar problem (copy constructor and abstact member) in some other parts of program, not related to DirectX.

Comment: Can you add another interface to your implementation that has a Clone function on it. Then, in the copy, you could QI to your clone interface and call Clone to make a new copy of the instance. OR you could just use CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> and have all instances of Model share the same buffer.

Comment: @PolGraphic Alright, I'm no Direct3D wizard, but is it legal for two objects to share the same vertex/index buffers? If that's the case, then within your copy constructor you could simply set `constantBuffer` to `other.constantBuffer`.

Comment: @faranwath but `constantBuffer = other.constantBuffer` would not create a deep copy (I would have two pointers to same `ID3D11Buffer` - it's ok for index/vertex buffers but **NOT** ok for my per object constant buffer). I share same vertex/index buffers, but not the constant buffers (I have to create a copy of it). Sorry if I did not make it clear from start.

Comment: @PolGraphic You're right, that's why I asked if it's legal for two objects to share the buffer. I think cppguy knows more about this than I do.

Comment: Is the buffer class YOUR implementation or some stock D3D class?

Comment: @cppguy Constant buffer? Nope. It's `DirectX::ID3D11Buffer` and In my post, I have wrote how I initialise it with `device->CreateBuffer(...)`.

Comment: ID3D11Buffer points to a COM object, so copying it won't do you any good.